# Animação na mudança do display em HTML

Tags: javascript, html, div, animação, css-animations

## Olá meus queridos amigos programadores deste nosso Brasil!

Preciso da ajuda dos senhores na seguinte questão:
 Tenho um botão que quando apertado muda o display de uma div para block. Assim:

### CSS

```
#form-pergunta {
  display: none;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
function obj(x) {
 return document.getElementById(x);
}

function ApertarBotao() {
 obj("form-pergunta").style.display = "block";
}
```

Ai eu chamo a função ApertarBotao() lá no HTML com onclick...
Gostaria de saber como animar essa mudança de display... Tipo... fazer a div form-pergunta aparecer lentamente de cima para baixo.

Comment: De cima para baixo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acho que isso pode te ajudar um pouco:

```js
    function obj(x) {
        return document.getElementById(x);
    }

    function ApertarBotao() {
        obj("form-pergunta").style.display = "block";
    }
```

```css
    #form-pergunta{
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: red;
        display: none;
        -webkit-animation: animate-div 3s;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes animate-div {
        from { opacity: 0; margin-top: -150px;}
        to { opacity: 1;margin-top: 0px;}
    }
```

```html
    <div id="form-pergunta"></div>
    <button onclick="ApertarBotao()">Show Div</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Aqui tem, deve ajustar o `id` do elemento a aparecer e o tempo dentro da funçao `onclick` do botão

```js
function fadeIn(elem, speed) {
   if(!elem.style.opacity)
   {
       elem.style.opacity = 0;
   }
   var op = setInterval(function(){
      if(elem.style.opacity == 1) clearInterval(op);
      elem.style.opacity = parseFloat(elem.style.opacity) + 0.03;
   }, speed /100);
}
```

```css
div {
   width: 200px;
   opacity: 0;
   height: 200px;
   background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="fadeIn(hey, 2000)">clica aqui</button>
<div id="hey"></div>
```